# svg images loading on canvas after second time refresh browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to load the saved svg on canvas so that i can modify and save it again. so i am getting the array in hidden field and loading that array in to the canvas :

```html
<input type="hidden" name="insert_arry" value='<?=htmlspecialchars($get_result[$insert])?>' id="insert_arry">
```

```js
// script for loading the json array of svg on canvas
// loading the view of canvas here
opc_Canvas_Load(
  opc_View[opc_Current_View].path.replace('thumb','large'),
  opc_Current_View
  );
responsive_slide('opc_Product_Slider', 'pWrapper');
jq(window).resize(function() {
  opc_Canvas_Load(opc_OverlayImg, opc_Current_View);
});

// tried to load the div first of canvas using jquery, won't work
$(".handler-area").first().css('display', 'block');

// getting the array stored in to the hidden field
var insert_arry = jq('#insert_arry').val();

// loading the json array in canvas
canvas.loadFromJSON(insert_arry.substring(1, insert_arry.length - 1));
```

Object loads on canvas but it shows the images after refresh browsers. this may be the image loading issue but couldn't find exact to resolve issue.

Comment: `loadFromJSON` comes from fabric.js library ? Could you add an [MCVE] with some minimal data passed in-lieu of `<?=htmlspecialchars($get_result[$insert])?>` ?

Comment: [{"objects":[],"background":"","backgroundImage":{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":1200,"height":960,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false}]

Comment: its too big array so i couldn't put  all content in array .. i just shortened array content.

Comment: Wow ... Aftera lot of try i m done with this task
///// **working code**
`var insert_arry = jq('#insert_arry').val();
   canvas.loadFromJSON(insert_arry.substring(1, insert_arry .length-1));
   var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function() {
    opc_Canvas_Load(opc_View[opc_Current_View].path.replace('thumb', 'large'), opc_Current_View);
    responsive_slide('opc_Product_Slider', 'pWrapper');

    jq(window).resize(function() {
     opc_Canvas_Load(opc_OverlayImg, opc_Current_View);
    });
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // Wow ... Aftera lot of try i m done with this task 
 ///// working code 

 var insert_arry = jq('#insert_arry').val(); 
 canvas.loadFromJSON(insert_arry.substring(1, insert_arry .length-1));
 var  img = new Image(); img.onload = function() { 
 opc_Canvas_Load(opc_View[opc_Current_View].path.replace(‌​'thumb', 'large'), 
 opc_Current_View); responsive_slide('opc_Product_Slider', 'pWrapper'); 
 jq(window).resize(function() { opc_Canvas_Load(opc_OverlayImg, opc_Current_View); }); }
```

Nice !!!!!